# js function gets error in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, popup

I am getting an error in the console:

> avatargallery:351 Uncaught TypeError: picwin.attachEvent is not a
>   function
>       at popitpic (avatarpopup.js:11)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (avatargallery:351) popitpic @ avatarpopup.js:11 onclick @ avatargallery:351
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :    unknown

Here is my code

```
/* this is the function that is used for the avatar larger images to be shown in a popup window.  */

function popitpic(url) 
{
    picwin=window.open( url,  'popwin','location=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,directories=0,resizable=0,height=250,width=250');

    if ( window.addEventListner )
    {
         picwin.addEventListener( "load", picwinload, false );
    } else {
         picwin.attachEvent( "onload", picwinload );
    }

    function picwinload( )
    {
        picwin.moveTo(0,0);
        picwin.document.body.bgColor="#100206";
    }

}//close function
```

Comment: There is a typo in your code: `addEventListner`. The `if` statement always valuates to `false`. Since non IE browsers do not support the `attachEvent` method you get that error.

Comment: Holy moly... thanks for that i forget the e... errrr   thanks so much, yes i must be blind lol